Can not modify value in javascript in Apigee policy
Apigee question : I am trying to modify variable & then use it in following flow, below is policy I am using but it seems value of offsetValue is always empty no matter how I access.
    <AssignVariable>
        <Name>data.request.offset</Name>
        <Value>0</Value>
    </AssignVariable>
    <AssignMessage>
        <Set>
            <Payload contentType="application/javascript">
                context.setVariable("offsetValue", 50);
            </Payload>
        </Set>
    </AssignMessage>
    <AssignVariable>
        <Name>data.request.offset</Name>
        <Value ref="offsetValue" />
    </AssignVariable>

I have tried to set value in JavaScript but its not working.

Your assign message policy configuration is incorrect.
Assuming you need the variable in the same policy, you'll need to configure it as follows -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="AM-SetVars">
    <DisplayName>AM-SetVars</DisplayName>
    <Properties/>
    <AssignVariable><!-- This is redundant though -->
        <Name>data.request.offset</Name>
        <Value>0</Value>
    </AssignVariable>
    <AssignVariable>
        <Name>offsetValue</Name>
        <Value>50</Value>
    </AssignVariable>
    <AssignVariable>
        <Name>data.request.offset</Name>
        <Ref>offsetValue</Ref>
    </AssignVariable>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="request"/>
</AssignMessage>

Please look up the docs for more information on the assign message policy.
Also, if you are looking to use Javascript to do this, you'll need to add the Javascript policy.
